# Adicionar MySQL Connector ao pacote de instação

Tags: c#, mysql, instalador

Tenho um *Windows Forms* que se conecta a uma base de dados *MySQL* remota (está num servidor). Basicamente, tudo que ele faz é ler dados de uma tabela, nem escreve nem nada. Estou utilizando o *Entity Framework* e meu projeto possui as seguintes dependências referentes ao *Mysql*: *MySql.Data*, *MySql.Data.Entity.EF6*.

Bom, até ai tudo perfeito! A aplicação está pronta e funcionando corretamente.
O problema é o seguinte, toda vez que levo a aplicação até um cliente novo, obrigatoriamente tenho que instalar o *MysqlConnector* na mão antes de instalar meu sistema, [link do download](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation.html).

Não tem como incluir esse bendito como pré-requisito no meu instalador? Ao gerar o install ele já ir automaticamente com o projeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola, eu tive esse problema que de ter que instalar programa manualmente, mas achei esse instalador com o Visual Studio, com ele vc consegui colocar a dependência de programas e pode colocar para instalar antes da aplicação, vou colocar um link que explica o procedimento certinho, tem varias funções que pode ajudar bastante.

Vou colocar o Passo a Passo:
Você vai baixar o programa Installer Projects do Visual Studio, tem tanto pelo Nuget dentro do visual ou pode achar no site da Microsoft.
Vai adicionar um novo projeto já no que vc criou. Em ADD > New Projetc > Other Project Type > Visual Studio Installer > Seleciona "Setup Project".
Ele vai Criar abaixo da sua solução uma pasta, basta vc clicar com direito e adicionar seu diretório, apos isso vc vai colocar as dependências, e seleciona o próprio exe do Mysql, ou vc pode colocar para ele baixar do site do fornecedor. 
Após isso tudo é só compilar, será gerado um Setup, e um .msi, é só levar isso nos clientes e o programa faz o resto da instalação sozinho.
Para melhor detalhamento pode olhar o link, que existe outras funções como adicionar atalhos, registros e tudo mais, é bem fácil e funcional

Link: http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2017/01/25/criando-um-instalador-com-o-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Muito completo o instalador! Realmente superior ao convencional disponível no VS. Com esse instalador consegui localizar onde estava o problema no build do meu sistema. Agora gerei um .msi com todos arquivos necessários, incluindo o MySQLConnector! Obrigado.

Comment: Sim é Muito Eficiente até com manipulação de registro e ordem de instalação de programas. que bom que ajudou